# SQL result from Rows to Column

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

How to get sql result by using sqlplus in shell script in column form like below. Please note 1st column is Header and 2nd column the row value (only 1 row need to be displayed as no other matching.)

```
STAT_DATE       20180515

SERVER_NAME   abcd3363

Hits1         112389

Hits2         659405
```

Whereas simple by select command I get as below.

```
STAT_DATE   SERVER_NAME     Hits1     Hits2

----------- --------------  -------- --------

20180515    abcd3363        112389   659405
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: We are using Oracle 12c

Answer (score 0):

This should help -

```
CREATE TABLE tabl1
    (STAT_DATE varchar2(11), SERVER_NAME varchar2(14), Hits1 varchar2(8), Hits2 varchar2(8))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO tabl1 (STAT_DATE, SERVER_NAME, Hits1, Hits2)
         VALUES ('20180515', 'abcd3363', '112389', '659405')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Query -

```
select * from tabl1
unpivot (vals for cols in (STAT_DATE as 'STAT_DATE', SERVER_NAME AS 'SERVER_NAME', Hits1 AS 'Hits1', Hits2 AS 'Hits2'));
;
```

Output -

```
COLS        VALS
STAT_DATE   20180515
SERVER_NAME abcd3363
Hits1       112389
Hits2       659405
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible without creating table  and generalizing this for any number of rows.

Comment: @harshitsrivastava If you want to generalize this to any number of rows, then you'll need a column which contains the row number/label.